# How to clear all file associations for a specific program on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

Calibre seems to associate itself with all file types supported by the program (the registry entries aren't cleared upon removal):

```
Registry Key    Name
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities ApplicationDescription
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities ApplicationName
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities ApplicationIcon
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .djvu
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .prc
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .imp
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .cbz
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .txt
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .ibook
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .cbc
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .book
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .azw1
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .pobi
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .htm
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .html
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .cbr
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .mobi
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .djv
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .ps
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .azw3
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .text
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .odt
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .chm
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .md
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .markdown
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .pdb
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .pdf
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .epub
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .docm
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .lrx
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .rtf
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .lrf
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .fb2
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .docx
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .azw
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .doc
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .xhtml
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .pml
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .ibooks
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .tpz
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations    .xps
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    image/vnd.djvu
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-mobipocket-ebook
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/vnd.accpac.simply.imp
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-cbz
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    text/plain
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-ibooks+zip
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-cbc
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-maker
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-topaz-ebook
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-mobipocket-subscription
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    text/html
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-cbr
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/postscript
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-mobi8-ebook
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    chemical/x-chemdraw
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    text/x-markdown
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/ereader
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/pdf
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/epub+zip
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/x-sony-bbeb
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    text/rtf
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    text/fb2+xml
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/msword
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/xhtml+xml
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/vnd.ctc-posml
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations    application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument
HKCU\Software\calibre\calibre64bit\Capabilities\shell\open\command   
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities  ApplicationDescription
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities  ApplicationName
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities  ApplicationIcon
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .xhtml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .azw3
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .epub
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .htm
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .html
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .docx
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/xhtml+xml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-mobi8-ebook
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/epub+zip
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations text/html
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
HKCU\Software\calibre\Editor64bit\Capabilities\shell\open\command    
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities  ApplicationDescription
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities  ApplicationName
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities  ApplicationIcon
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .djvu
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .prc
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .azw3
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .cbc
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .pobi
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .htm
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .html
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .cbr
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .shtml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .opf
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .mobi
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .djv
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .txt
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .text
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .odt
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .chm
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .md
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .markdown
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .pdb
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .pdf
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .epub
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .docm
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .rtf
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .lrf
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .fb2
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .docx
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .azw
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .xhtml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .pml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\FileAssociations .cbz
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations image/vnd.djvu
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-mobipocket-ebook
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-mobi8-ebook
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-cbc
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-mobipocket-subscription
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations text/html
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-cbr
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/oebps-package+xml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations text/plain
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations chemical/x-chemdraw
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations text/x-markdown
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/ereader
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/pdf
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/epub+zip
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations text/rtf
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-sony-bbeb
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations text/fb2+xml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/xhtml+xml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/vnd.ctc-posml
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\MimeAssociations application/x-cbz
HKCU\Software\calibre\Viewer64bit\Capabilities\shell\open\command    
HKCU\Software\Classes\.azw1\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.AZW1
HKCU\Software\Classes\.azw3\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.AZW3
HKCU\Software\Classes\.azw3\OpenWithProgIDs calibreEditor64bit.AssocFile.AZW3
HKCU\Software\Classes\.azw3\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.AZW3
HKCU\Software\Classes\.azw\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.AZW
HKCU\Software\Classes\.azw\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.AZW
HKCU\Software\Classes\.book\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.BOOK
HKCU\Software\Classes\.cbc\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.CBC
HKCU\Software\Classes\.cbc\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.CBC
HKCU\Software\Classes\.cbr\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.CBR
HKCU\Software\Classes\.cbr\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.CBR
HKCU\Software\Classes\.cbz\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.CBZ
HKCU\Software\Classes\.cbz\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.CBZ
HKCU\Software\Classes\.chm\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.CHM
HKCU\Software\Classes\.chm\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.CHM
HKCU\Software\Classes\.djv\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.DJV
HKCU\Software\Classes\.djv\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.DJV
HKCU\Software\Classes\.djvu\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.DJVU
HKCU\Software\Classes\.djvu\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.DJVU
HKCU\Software\Classes\.doc\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.DOC
HKCU\Software\Classes\.docm\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.DOCM
HKCU\Software\Classes\.docm\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.DOCM
HKCU\Software\Classes\.docx\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.DOCX
HKCU\Software\Classes\.docx\OpenWithProgIDs calibreEditor64bit.AssocFile.DOCX
HKCU\Software\Classes\.docx\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.DOCX
HKCU\Software\Classes\.epub\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.EPUB
HKCU\Software\Classes\.epub\OpenWithProgIDs calibreEditor64bit.AssocFile.EPUB
HKCU\Software\Classes\.epub\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.EPUB
HKCU\Software\Classes\.fb2\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.FB2
HKCU\Software\Classes\.fb2\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.FB2
HKCU\Software\Classes\.htm\OpenWithProgids  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.HTM
HKCU\Software\Classes\.htm\OpenWithProgids  calibreEditor64bit.AssocFile.HTM
HKCU\Software\Classes\.htm\OpenWithProgids  calibre64bit.AssocFile.HTM
HKCU\Software\Classes\.html\OpenWithProgids calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.HTML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.html\OpenWithProgids calibreEditor64bit.AssocFile.HTML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.html\OpenWithProgids calibre64bit.AssocFile.HTML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.ibook\OpenWithProgIDs    calibre64bit.AssocFile.IBOOK
HKCU\Software\Classes\.ibooks\OpenWithProgIDs   calibre64bit.AssocFile.IBOOKS
HKCU\Software\Classes\.imp\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.IMP
HKCU\Software\Classes\.lrf\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.LRF
HKCU\Software\Classes\.lrf\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.LRF
HKCU\Software\Classes\.lrx\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.LRX
HKCU\Software\Classes\.markdown\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.MARKDOWN
HKCU\Software\Classes\.markdown\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.MARKDOWN
HKCU\Software\Classes\.md\OpenWithProgIDs   calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.MD
HKCU\Software\Classes\.md\OpenWithProgIDs   calibre64bit.AssocFile.MD
HKCU\Software\Classes\.mobi\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.MOBI
HKCU\Software\Classes\.mobi\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.MOBI
HKCU\Software\Classes\.odt\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.ODT
HKCU\Software\Classes\.odt\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.ODT
HKCU\Software\Classes\.opf\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.OPF
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pdb\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.PDB
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pdb\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.PDB
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pdf\OpenWithProgids  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.PDF
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pdf\OpenWithProgids  calibre64bit.AssocFile.PDF
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pml\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.PML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pml\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.PML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pobi\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.POBI
HKCU\Software\Classes\.pobi\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.POBI
HKCU\Software\Classes\.prc\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.PRC
HKCU\Software\Classes\.prc\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.PRC
HKCU\Software\Classes\.ps\OpenWithProgIDs   calibre64bit.AssocFile.PS
HKCU\Software\Classes\.rtf\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.RTF
HKCU\Software\Classes\.rtf\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.RTF
HKCU\Software\Classes\.shtml\OpenWithProgids    calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.SHTML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.text\OpenWithProgIDs calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.TEXT
HKCU\Software\Classes\.text\OpenWithProgIDs calibre64bit.AssocFile.TEXT
HKCU\Software\Classes\.tpz\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.TPZ
HKCU\Software\Classes\.txt\OpenWithProgIDs  calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.TXT
HKCU\Software\Classes\.txt\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.TXT
HKCU\Software\Classes\.xhtml\OpenWithProgids    calibreViewer64bit.AssocFile.XHTML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.xhtml\OpenWithProgids    calibreEditor64bit.AssocFile.XHTML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.xhtml\OpenWithProgids    calibre64bit.AssocFile.XHTML
HKCU\Software\Classes\.xps\OpenWithProgIDs  calibre64bit.AssocFile.XPS
```

[...] I can't share all entries due to the Stack Exchange's 30,000-character limitation. In total there are over 700 `HKCU\Software` key entries containing `calibre` (searched with [Nirsoft's Regscanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html)).

Are there other, safer ways to clear the software associations in addition to mass-deleting registry entries? Because Calibre still appears in the Windows 10's "open with" menus the leftover values have real implications:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried Piriform CCleaner's registry cleaner tool?

Comment: @spikey_richie: I've taken a look, but [these tools aren't recommended by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2563254/microsoft-support-policy-for-the-use-of-registry-cleaning-utilities) and I didn't find a way to filter results by name in the program.